# ReSharper: Find Usages of an optional parameter

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, optional-parameters

If I have a function with optional parameter, is there an easy way to find all the locations in my code that call that function and pass a value to that parameter?

The function has many non-default parameters, so scanning the usual Find Usages results of places that call the function is problematic, as it trims the lines and I can't see if the optional parameter is used.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With your cursor on the parameter, choose `ReSharper | Inspect | Value Origin`, or from the keyboard, `Inspect This` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then `Value Origin`.

You will get an Inspection Results window with all the places that *explicitly* assign that parameter a value.

Comment: but how can find usages that the parameter is assigned implicitly (without param: )?

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way is changing Signature of the method. In other word you can change **type** of the parameter to another type (that is not used by parameters for safety) and see Errors list after rebuild.
By this way you can find *all* (not only *explicitly*) usages of the parameter.