# Is there anyway to find usages of optional parameters in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I found this answer concerning ReSharper but nothing for Visual Studio itself.

[ReSharper: Find Usages of an optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505698/resharper-find-usages-of-an-optional-parameter)

I have a method that's called in many places so when I run a `Find All References` command it is a bit unwieldy to search for things that use this optional parameter.

Comment: Don't have access to vs right now, so can't answer, but you could use a hack, if nothing else helps: remove this parameter and compile. Errors will show the usage places.

Comment: That did do the trick, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although it gets tricky with multiple optional parameters: create a method which does not have the last optional parameter and all the references to this new method will be the ones which don't specify the optional argument.